# Why is https being forced locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, initialization, config, development-environment

I recently added in a simple `config.force_ssl` to my `production.rb` after obtaining a certificate. Added nothing to `development.rb`.

I pushed this up to production, and tried running locally, but now https is being forced on localhost:3000.

So I first tried modifying `config.force_ssl` to `config.force_ssl = true unless Rails.env.development?`. Keep in mind, this line only exists within `production.rb`. Still being forced.

Then I tried commenting the line out completely. Still being forced.

I restarted the server each time.

I'm starting the server with foreman. My procfile is:

```
web: rails s -p 3000
client: sh -c 'rm app/assets/webpack/* || true && cd client && bundle exec rake react_on_rails:locale && yarn run build:development'
```

Was something cached the first time I did this?

Is the `client` portion of my Procfile doing something?

Comment: Have you tried restarting spring?

Comment: If you mean by using `spring stop`, then yes. Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to your browser cache, try cleaning your cache and App data or use different browser.

If once your `localhost` is in `https`, then it will still use `https` unless browser cache and data removed.

You can also change port where rails application is running.